# Removing specific node on XML DOM using java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, screen-scraping

Working on project to remove specific dependency in pom.xml, but getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
...
<dependencies>
...
<dependency> 
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId> 
        <version>1.3.10</version>
</dependency>
...
</dependencies>
...
</project>
```

What to remove dependency struts-core using XML DOM in java.

**ModifyXMLFIleInJava.java**

```
public class ModifyXMLFileInJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "src/migrate/pom.xml";
        File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            // parse xml file and load into document
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // delete element
            deleteElement(doc);
            
            writeXMLFile(doc);


        } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException | TransformerException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void writeXMLFile(Document doc)
    throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("src/migrate/pom2.xml"));
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");
    }



    /**
     * Delete gender element from User element
     * @param doc
     */
    private static void deleteElement(Document doc) {
        NodeList deps = doc.getElementsByTagName("dependency");
        for (int i = 0; i < deps.getLength(); i++) {
            Node dep= deps.item(i);
            if(dep.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                NodeList children  = dep.getChildNodes();
                for(int j=0; j<children.getLength() ; j++) {
                    Node childNode = children.item(i);
                    if(childNode.getNodeName() == "artifactId") {
                        String artifactId = childNode.getTextContent();
                        if("struts-core".equals(artifactId)) {
                            childNode.getParentNode().removeChild(childNode);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

In this line of code in ModifyXMLFIleInJava.java getting **java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
if(childNode.getNodeName() == "artifactId") {
```

In the method deleteElement(..) is trying to find specific artifact id that is to be removed and remaining code is to be generated in new file called pom2.xml
Reading the pom.xml and storing to Dependeny.java objects works fine.

**Dependency.java**

```
public class Dependency {
    private String groupId;
    private String artifactId;
    private String version;
    private String scope;
    
    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }
    
    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }
    
    public String getArtifactId() {
        return artifactId;
    }
    
    public void setArtifactId(String artifactId) {
        this.artifactId = artifactId;
    }
    
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    
    public String getScope() {
        return scope;
    }
    
    public void setScope(String scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }
    
     public String toString() {
         return "dependency [groupid=" + groupId + ", artifactId=" + artifactId +", version="+version + ", scope="+scope +"]";
     }
}
```

Comment: Node childNode = children.item(i); // should be `j` rather than `i`

Comment: Opps, small error, @Jaybird post as answer.